# Как хранить историю наличия и приходов/расходов в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, хранение-данных, интернет-магазин

Нужно организовать создание и хранение данных на сайте php+mysql: 
- актуальное наличие, которое можно менять вручную (модель, размер, цвет, количество)
- приходы (модель, размер, цвет, количество)
- расходы (модель, размер, цвет, количество, цена)
- возможность сформировать отчетную таблицу в заданном интервале времени, например, месяц.

1. Как правильно организовать хранение данных с учетом того, что приходов, расходов и изменений наличия вручную может быть по несколько в день и каждая операция может содержать десятки строк?

Моя идея хранить актуальное наличие, каждый раз перезаписывая его после операции. Изменения наличия вручную хранить как отдельные операции по приходу/расходу. Ежемесячно создавать лог наличия моделей, а в случае необходимости построить отчет, брать ближайший лог наличия и от него высчитывать операции в заданном интервале.

2. Как хранить историю наличия, если цена товара может быть разной в зависимости от времени прихода на склад?

Например, может быть ситуация, когда на складе есть 100 моделей по 10 размеров по 10 цветов по 30 штук, итого 300 000 позиций. Хранить в строках с разделителями? В файлах?

Comment: никаких строк с разделителями и файлов. следуйте нормальным формам (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) По написанному вижу всего 2 основные таблицы. некие "документы", которые объединяют операции с несколькими позициями и собственно товар, где лежат записи о всех изменениях количества (+-). В этой же таблице можно фиксировать и складские остатки в виде записей специального типа. Ну конечно наверняка будет еще с десяток справочных таблиц вроде товаров, их видов, типов и т.п.

Comment: Что касается цен, никаких проблем не вижу, если есть товар A по 1р и по 2р, то хранить 2 записи, сколько на складе по 1р и сколько по 2р. ну и вводить некий механизм определения при списании со склада, какой из товаров уходит первым

Comment: Актуальное количество скорее всего хранить не надо. Его всегда можно вычислить исходя из последней записи складских остатков и последующих операций движения. Смысл хранения этой информации может появится только при проблемах с производительностью, тогда стоит хранить их отдельно и обновлять автоматически триггерами при добавлении записей движения

Comment: @Mike Допустимо ли, если есть товар А по 1р. - 2шт. и по 2р. - 4шт. хранить каждую единицу в отдельной строке, а при списании удалять необходимое количество строк, сортируя, например по уменьшению цены? Тогда проще организовать приходы и списание, несмотря на цены, и сортировать и суммировать операции построчно при формировании отчетов

Comment: лучше избежать удаления/модификации строк. они же отражают реальную операцию и вы наверняка захотите видеть сколько за период всего поступило того или иного товара. А если вы запись удалите, то уже этого не узнаете. добавляете еще одну запись, но с минусом

Comment: Вообще БД должна отражать реальные процессы и документы. Наверняка на движение по складу есть некие накладные. Вот и в БД должны быть эти самые накладные и их строки. Тогда вы всегда сможете увидеть что такого то числа по накладной такой то, товаровед такой то взял со склада столько то того то или положил столько то того то. И этого уже достаточно что бы построить любую отчетность. А все остальное, типа хранения текущих остатков - это уже избыточные данные и они вводятся в модель позже, когда поймем что они нужны для быстродействия и/или удобства недопущения отрицательных количеств при списани

Comment: @Mike хранение текущих остатков мне необходимо, чтобы показывать их на сайте при заказе без лишних операций. С остальными вопросами все понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну да, тогда их в отдельную таблицу и вести ее тирггерами на таблице с движением. И да, запись из нее можно удалять при достижении нуля.